# Detect class inside ul list, if not found delete li:first-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this structure:

```
<ul id="#my-list">

<li><a class="class-1" href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a class="class-2" href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a class="class-3" href="#">Link</a></li>

</ul>
```

I want jquery to check if **.class-1** inside **#my-list** exists, if not then it should delete  **.li** (just the first one).

Basically, when the first link is deleted, the first li element should be removed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#my-list:has(.class-1) li:first').remove()
```

That would of course require an ID like:

```
<ul id="my-list">
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXGzR/)

According to your question, you'd like to do the opposite for some strange reason, and that would be :

```
$('#my-list:not(:has(.class-1)) li:first').remove()
```

but the question is, how are you deleting the anchor, and why not just delete the list item instead ?

Comment: i think it should be `$('#my-list:not(:has(.class-1)) li:first').remove()` or `$('#my-list').not(':has(.class-1)').find('li:first').remove()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yup, was adding that now, but I don't really see the use case !

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: I think you don't know what `:has` does: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/.

Comment: Perhaps my question was a bit confusing, but the answer is right, it worked for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, when the first link is deleted, the first li element should be removed as well.

Sounds like you want:

```
$('#my-list > li').first().filter(function() {
   return $(this).find('a').length === 0;
}).remove();
```

If you want to apply this to all `li` elements, not just the first one, simply omit `.first()`.

Comment: this answer is way off

Comment: @MuhammadUmer How so? I upvoted it, I think it could be useful, as the OP was rather unclear.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Please elaborate.

Comment: it's not even checking for `.class-1`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Yes, I wrote a *general* solution based on the part of the question that I quoted (*"Basically, when the first link is deleted, the first li element should be removed as well."*). It removes the first `li` element if it doesn't contain a link anymore. It's really trivial to extend it to inlcude `.class-1` if desired (just use `.find('a.class-1')`).

Comment: it's not wrong just not what op had in mind. But technique is solid. So yea.